# What are some techniques to avoid digital distraction?

Tags: writers-block, process, discipline, time-management

I'm a modern day writer. I learned to type on a word processor when I was eight or nine. If you gave me a typewriter (which would be super cool of you,) I wouldn't really know how to use it well. I also like having the internet at my fingertips. But my biggest problem is that sometimes I get lost in the internet rabbit-hole. I end up with seven blog posts, a couple of news articles, a few Wikipedia pages, at least ten to twelve tabs for Stack Exchange. Before I know it, I've spent four hours not writing anything and it's time for sleep.

Part of the problem is that the internet is useful. There is legitimate and much needed information there. And well-timed rests and mind breaks are also important. So how do I stay focused. Find the information I need and get back to work.

Comment: Related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38/writing-discipline

Comment: I'm assuming that you use a windows computer to write. Is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only problem is when I find the need for research something in the internet for my writing. I'll say what works for me.

- I use [Focus Writer](https://gottcode.org/focuswriter/)
- I turn off not only my computer's wi-fi, but my router as well
- When I feel the shallow need of searching for something, I write down what exactly I want to know and leave it there.
- So when I really feel the need for researching, I turn on the router again and do it. (It might be dangerous because I can end up in a search-loop-hole, but I use a browser extension called "Impulse Blocker" to help me with that. It does'nt work always)

Lastly, but not least, you talked about **mind breaks.** What you really want to aim is being bored. Yes, being bored and tedium. Because your mind in that state keeps working and if you get yourself distracted with anything else, you lose that subconsciouss processing. Don't do anything, allow yourself to be bored, and you'll see how much this is helpful.

Comment: Taking a shower is definitely my best tedium mind break. I just need to find more of those.

Comment: Here's a +1 for the third bullet point alone. Don't try to figure out everything in the moment; just make a note to yourself that you'll need to do it, and move on.